# Breaking out of a do while loop in an async task after parsing all data in a URLConnection

Tags: java, android

How would i end the do while loop if there is only one line of data or if the next line is empty?

```
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String inputLine = "";

    try {
        do {
            JSONData += inputLine;
        }
     }
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use,

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null && !inputLine.isEmpty());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break to loop with `break`.

To check for empty or null value, you can use this example:

```
//in loop
if(inputLine == null || inputLine.isEmpty()) { 
  break; 
}
```

Comment: You should check for `null` before checking for `isEmpty()` or you will get a NullPointerException.